# MySQL describe | more

Tags: mysql

With my current setup, it's going to be very hard, if not impossible, to get my terminal window to scroll up and down. That means I can only see 25 rows of text at once. If I have to display something longer, I use |more to be able to scroll through it, like this:

```
ifconfig | more
```

But what can I do when a MySQL statement returns more than 25 lines?

```
describe mysql.user;
```

I can't just add "| more" in MySQL, and "limit 5" would be invalid syntax here. How can I view the rows a few at a time?

Comment: You are confusing commands in the command line with mysql queries/commands run from inside MySQL.

You can execute queries from the command line with `-e` and then feed them to `more` or `less` or whatever else (save them to a file, etc.) :  `mysql -u qaz -p -e 'describe mysql.user;' | more`

Comment: I think you can also use the `pager` inside MySQL, with for example: `pager less` and then your output will "page" nicely.

Answer (score 1):

In the MySQL shell, enter

```
pager less
```

Then enter your query. Use Enter to scroll down and 'q' to stop browsing the results.

My system doesn't have less, so I used more instead:

```
pager more
```

[More can scroll down and quit like less, but it can't scroll up.](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/604/isnt-less-just-more)

Answer (score 0):

The "less command is far more flexible - check it out - forward and back an arbitrary number of lines - sophisticated searches - it's great. Otherwise, use the tee command to output what you need to a file.

[EDIT] I forgot to specify (thanks @ypercube) that you have to set your pager to less mysql> pager less; To install it, use sudo apt-get install less (or whatever the syntax is for your distro).